# How to temporarily disable smart-operator?

Tags: python

I am using smart-operator for Python programming, and I like to use it. However I have also found it annoying for inputting:

1. regular expressions like `.*`
2. equals (`=`) in an function.

I would like to disable it by a prefix shortcut, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always type characters literally by hitting `C-q` first.

1. `C-q .` will type a dot, wherever you are.
2. `C-q =` will always insert a `=`.

Comment: Is this what you were asking for? I'm not 100% sure I understood you question.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot for help!